# Why does my sytem have muptiple addresses on interface wlo1?

Tags: network-interface, ipv6

I tried to init docker swarm

```
Error response from daemon: could not choose an IP address to advertise since this system has multiple addresses on interface wlo1
```

Ok,I will advertis address.

```
ip a
```

shows

```
2: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:94:02:93:05:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp3s0
    inet 192.168.0.16/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
       valid_lft 600563sec preferred_lft 600563sec
    inet6 2a06:7d14:17fe:6900::1/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 2587763sec preferred_lft 859763sec
    inet6 2a06:7d14:17fe:6900:d3d8:7e5b:daab:7941/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 600564sec preferred_lft 81950sec
    inet6 2a06:7d14:17fe:6900:8849:3581:5e29:1a15/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 2591987sec preferred_lft 863987sec
    inet6 fe80::f7eb:ac02:1d60:c4f5/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Can someone explain muliple interafaces?